# How to set the number of items in mat-autocomplete

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm now trying to change the number of items in a mat-autocomplete for a while without success. I'm using material.angular.io

Here's my code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-and-search',
  templateUrl: './add-and-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-and-search.component.css']
})
export class AddAndSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  items: string[] = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>Search...</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Search..." [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-optgroup label="Items">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
    <mat-option><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add</mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

From the docs I learned that the autocomplete panel has a constant height of 256px (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT).

My question is: How can I change the autocomplete panel to display more items. Let's say 10. If there is no intended way of doing this could someone give me a hint on a CSS trick to set the height e.g. to 512px instead of the default 256px?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the height of the autocomplete panel by overwriting the max-height like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel {
 max-height: 512px !important; 
}
```

[See it in action here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjawh9?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.css).

Comment: Thank you, that solves to issue for me. I'm keeping the question open a bit. I'm still wondering if there is no intended way on setting the number of items that should be shown in the panel.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that but if I had to guess, I'd say that this wouldn't be possible as there is assumed to be no universal row height for a given panel. In other words, since row height can vary depending on content, the # of lines configuration couldn't possibly configure without extensive calculations.